Other ways to represent a real number
This is a question that I thought of while reading about continued fractions, but I have no background in number theory, so probably the answer is known to number theorists, but I could not find it.
Nowadays, we usually represent a real number using decimals. We have that numbers having repeating decimals are precisely the rational numbers (for finite decimals, we can think if them as having repeating 0s at the end).
Another way to represent a real number is by using continued fractions. In that setting, rational numbers have finite continued fractions, and quadratic algebraic numbers have repeating entries.
My question is : is there a way to represent real numbers by an infinite sequence of non-negative integers so that cubic algebraic numbers have repeating entries? Ideally, rational and quadratic algebraic numbers would also have nice properties, but I doubt we can fulfill all these criterias simultaneously.
Of course, the next step would be to ask this question for algebraic numbers of higher degrees.
Edit : As said by MartianInvader, I should add properties to the answer I want. The sequence should somehow encode an infinite sum that converge to the real number.

There are certainly ways to make a representation (just enumerate the cubic algebraic numbers and encode them all in the first integer entry, for example), but I feel like there are other unspoken properties you'd like to have of this representation?

You are right. This question was only by curiosity, so I must admit I haven't thought about properties. But your example show that I should have. Maybe they should encode an infinite sum equal to the real number, as decimals and continued fractions do?

There are such generalizations dating back to Jacobi and Perron, e.g. see Abrate et al. Periodic representations for cubic irrationalities for references.

This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!
